Print multiple DataGridViews using DGVPrinterHelper or Combine DGVs into a single document to print
I am using DGVPrinterHelper to print several DataGridViews (DGVs) at once. Currently, for each DGV, I have to open a configuration window that looks like this:
.
The problem with this is that sometimes there is 10 or even more different DGVs and I have to sit there and just spam 'Print' till it finally reaches the end.
Is there a way to add all the DGVs to one document with each being its own page and then just print it once or a way to make me not have to go to that window for every DGV.
Here´s the code responsible for this in my application:
private void bttPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GenerateDataGridViewsForEachFixture();

    string partNumbersSubtitle = string.Join(", ", PartNumbers);

    foreach (var dataGrid in allDataGrids)
    {
        string fixtureNumber = dataGrid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string lista = PartNumbers[0];

        // Configura e imprime o DataGridView
        DGVPrinter printer = new DGVPrinter();
        printer.Title = "Table: " + fixtureNumber;
        printer.SubTitle = "Lists: " + partNumbersSubtitle;
        printer.SubTitleFormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
        printer.PageNumbers = true;
        printer.PageNumberInHeader = false;
        printer.PorportionalColumns = true;
        printer.HeaderCellAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        printer.Footer = "Print DGV";
        printer.PrintDataGridView(dataGrid);
    }

}

private void GenerateDataGridViewsForEachFixture()
{
    var orderedFixtureGroups = setData
        .GroupBy(data => data.Table)
        .ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => g
                .GroupBy(sd => sd.PartNumber)
                .Select(gp => gp.First())
                .OrderBy(sd => int.Parse(sd.Feeder))
                .ToList()
        );

    allDataGrids.Clear();

    foreach (var fixtureGroup in orderedFixtureGroups)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

        // Define the columns
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Table" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "TypeFeeder" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Feeder" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Position" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Pup" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "PartNumber" });
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn { Name = "Missing" }); 

        foreach (var data in fixtureGroup.Value)
        {
            dgv.Rows.Add(data.Table, data.TipoFeeder, data.Feeder, data.Position, data.Pup, data.PartNumber, false);
        }

        allDataGrids.Add(dgv);
    }
}


Is this the code you are using?

This is the code for the printing part, the whole code is much longer. This part of the code is working perfectly its really just having to confirm every single DGV of the print that I want to change and cant get to work.

"This is the code for the printing part, the whole code is much longer." - my comment was asking if https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer was the DGVPrinterHelper you were using.

Sorry for the confusion, I didn´t see there was a link connected to it. Yes that is the correct one. Very useful info on how the helper works on that forum, Thank you.
